# What is AWS Auto Scaling? and how Is it helpful for the large project?

Tags: amazon-web-services, scaling, auto

I need to maintain my large application in way that, it should be like an updated scale on the fly..?

Can anyone explain to me how it works?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ you could not find this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, You can use AWS Auto Scaling service for scale up or down which not only provide balance load but its also save your monthly cost and utilized the resources.AWS Auto Scaling is free to use. AWS Auto Scaling is enabled by Amazon CloudWatch, so service fees apply for CloudWatch and your application resources (such as Amazon EC2 instances, Elastic Load Balancing load balancers, etc.).

Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling helps you ensure that you have the correct number of Amazon EC2 instances available to handle the load for your application.

AWS Auto Scaling is a fast, easy way to optimize the performance and costs of your applications.

1. Setup scaling quickly
2. Make smart scaling decisions
3. Automatically maintain performance
4. Anticipate costs and avoid overspending

**How its works**

[image]

ref. links

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/what-is-amazon-ec2-auto-scaling.html

https://www.logicworks.com/blog/2017/12/common-mistakes-misconceptions-auto-scaling-aws/
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-auto-scaling-unified-scaling-for-your-cloud-applications/

Comment: Great ..! Many Thanks.